# Best way to parse comma separated list

Tags: ios, arrays, json, parsing, core-data

I am receiving a JSON packet from a server I am communicating with, one of the requests I get back has an item in the JSON array that returnes which is a string of comma separated strings.

it looks like this when I NSLog the JSON packet as an array.

```
(
    "\"Completed\",\"UnCompleted Value\",\"Damaged Value\"",
    "",
    0
)
```

I can access that first item of the JSON array like this

```
NSString *firstJSONString = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

I would then like to parse it the best/most efficient way as I am going to store the values into a coredata object.

So my question is how can I parse this comma separated string?

Comment: Can the quoted values have commas in them?

Comment: yes... apparently if there is anything like that inside the quotes it will have quotes around it.

Comment: Then do a little searching on parsing CSV files. You will need to do exactly the same - deal with quotes and commas that might be in values. There a popular CSV parer on github.

Comment: That is freaky -- kinda looks like the JSON array got mugged somewhere along the way.  You could wrap the string with `[]` and send it through JSON deserialize, but if there are no other complications then componentsSeparatedByString is probably the simplest.

Comment: okay going to look up csv parser then.. thanks

Comment: I have looked on github and I cannot find anything that parses an NSString (as a CSV) everything requieres csv files...

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *items = [firstJSONString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

or

```
NSArray *items = [firstJSONString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\",\""];
```

And then  delete `\"` from the first item and `\"` in the last one

Comment: This only works if the quoted values can't have commas in them.

Comment: @rmaddy is correct as this was going to be my first solution.. however I forgot to write that into my question.. sorry about that.

Comment: The `0` isn't part of the string -- it's a separate element in the "real" array, as is the final `""`.

Comment: so that second example removes all quotes from inside string quotes?